# Context popup hiding after Ajax postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am using this jQuery context popup menu extension:
http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/

This context menu is bound against an ASP.NET treeview adding a context menu to all items.

All contained within an update panel.

In order to select the item when right clicking, I am using JQuery to parse the postback from HREF that would normally fire when the tree item is being clicked, and using eval() against this HREF. This results in a post-back to IIS. Immediately after is my JQuery code for displaying the context menu. The context menu appears briefly however goes as soon as IIS returns the updated page data.

Just after some general advice on how people think is best to approach this. I can avoid this by making users LEFT click the tree node prior to right clicking it, but that just seems unintuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Sam, as far as I see it the whole idea is kind of wrong from the start, I am a .Net developer but I've always avoided introducing an update panel in my applications, if you look behind the curtains you will see that update panels insert a form tag within the application which kind'a runs at server, try to insert two forms with runat server attribute one within the other in a VS see what they say :). To be honest it's fairly easy to build a contextual menu with templates as layout; it's about 3 hour work and several others for testing.
   Getting back to your issue. I see that you have two options here: either learn how to open the menu from javascript and retain the position inside a hidden field before postback(on click/open) and after the postback occurs reopen the menu at the desired position/components, either search for the code which actually does the post back and prevent it in your case. Could be a click and if so all you need is an ev.preventDefault(), could be a submit and then you would need to set up a variable and on submit return false or something like that. Can't really give you the actual code solution without seeing the page which has this "bad" behaviour, anyhow left clicking is, as you said, not intuitive and frankly not an option in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Given time I'll probably get some edited code up providing an example. I agree, the situation isn't ideal but as I'm being paid for what they want I don't have a huge say.

Comment: I know the feeling:) still you could argue that a pure js/ajax solution would work a lot faster and bring a greater user experience, besides update panels don not update exactly what you need and can do a lot more traffic than originally intended. Regarding the sample, I don't have much time online right now , but in a few hours I might get back on this, I would rather have a link though:).